# accessing dynamically added checkbox in a function to check them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a page in php which loads a group of category from another php script
and those are check boxes.

format of check box

```
<input type='checkbox' class='cat-selector' id='Bussiness' data-toggle='checkbox'/>
<input type='checkbox' class='cat-selector' id='Marketting' data-toggle='checkbox'/>
```

Now if I have url **localhost/newproj/search?category=Business**
i want to check those category check boxes which are in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do something like this in jquery/client side code to see if your checkbox id is the same as the category parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/newproj/search?category=Business',
    success : function(data){
       $(".cat-selector").each(function(){
       if($(this).prop("id") === getParameterByName("category")){
          $(this).prop("checked","checked");
       }
    }); 
    } });

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

you would need jQuery 1.8 or later to use the prop function. Else you would have to use the attr function.

you could also do it on the server side as suggested in other answers.

Comment: thanks arvind, but i think this would have worked if those check box are not added dynamically..

Comment: are you loading the checkboxes on ajax?

Comment: have edited my answers. This would work for an ajax call.

Comment: thanks it gave me another idea..and it worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='checkbox' class='cat-selector' id='Bussiness' data-toggle='checkbox' <?php echo (isset($_GET['Category']) && $_GET['Category'] == 'Bussiness')?'checked':''?>/>
<input type='checkbox' class='cat-selector' id='Marketting' data-toggle='checkbox' <?php echo (isset($_GET['Category']) && $_GET['Category'] == 'Marketting')?'checked':''?>/>
```

Comment: i tried....but those check boxes are being loaded from another php script..

Comment: ok, you need to access get paramerters via javascript. try Arvind Sridharan answer above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use window.location.pathname

See this question:
[Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-javascript)

And then combine with jquery with attr('checked','checked') http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: i tried all these... even $(document).on() function...still looking for my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='cat-selector' id='Bussiness' value='Business' data-toggle='checkbox' <?php
echo (isset($_REQUEST['category']) && $_REQUEST['category']=='Business')?'checked':'' ?> />
Business
<input type='checkbox' value='Marketing' class='cat-selector' id='Marketting' data-toggle='checkbox' <?php
echo (isset($_REQUEST['category']) && $_REQUEST['category']=='Marketting')?'checked':'' ?> />
Marketing
```